# Why is serial voting not reversed?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

Some time ago (*more than a month now*), someone up-voted 11 of my answers in just the timespan of ~3 minutes (*see the screenshot*). It should have been reversed by the next day, but it is not.

[image: Serial Voting]

Why is this not removed? Or is there any case/scenario in which this will happen(*again*)?

---

**Edit:**

This is not coincidence that different users upvoted the answers at the same (*few seconds difference*) time which is highly unlikely to happen as the answer are highest voted answers (*at that time*) so, this is definitely serial voting.

My primary guess is that there are two (or more?) users involved in this. One is a serial voter and the other is a normal user who *might* have found my post useful and upvoted in the middle of the serial voting (*I think is the first post in the screenshot above which has 4 upvotes*), which might have caused the serial reversal algorithm to think that this is not *serial* voting. Again, two more questions arrive in my mind:

1. How many votes are considered as *serial*?
2. Is there a time duration that'll be considered as serial voting?

Example: If a user upvotes *5* posts in *4* minutes, it'll be considered as serial voting.

Another thought is that some user is very impressed from my answer/comment and found it very useful and has upvoted those posts as a *"thank you"* vote.

Comment: Maybe that someone used 11 different accounts? :P

Comment: @Cerbrus: That'd be an awful lot of browser sessions to tab through...

Comment: Actually, 4-6 accounts would be more manageable. 2-3 votes per account. ;-)

Comment: It has happened several times already on your account, little reason to assume it won't happen again.  Not unusual for accounts of users from your neck of the woods btw, possibly a skewed sense of patriotism.  Whomever does this is *very* unlikely to step forward and explain the technique he used.  Simply use a custom flag on one of the upvoted posts and explain what you saw.  A moderator has some odds of getting him larsoned.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for reply. AFAIK, this has happened only twice with me. The first time it was revered by the next day. But for second time, it's not

Comment: Can't see all of the titles, but your image seems to several common letters, very possibly the same answers.  In the 11 answers, I see a few as 6 different posts (could be more if 2 posts had the same first 2 letters).  That points to at least 3 different voters.  I'd wager that if it wasn't reversed, it is very possibly just a coincidence of timing.  But at a minimum, it could explain why it wasn't reversed since the votes came from multiple accounts.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I just went and actually found the spot in Tushar's rep- They are all different questions, some of them just start with the same letters. (For anyone interested in looking, it was Oct 2.)

Comment: Added Complete image for solving confusion

Comment: I am not one to talk with such high rep users discussing stuff but it might as well be a coincidence? 11 different people upvoting your question? :v I mean the reversal worked before on such events right? Something was different this time,thats for certain.

Comment: @NSNoob it can indeed be coincidence, but there is also a good possibility that it is not. Serial voting in any direction is damaging to the effectiveness of the site so it should at least be investigated. A flag for mod attention should do it if it isn't reversed automatically.

Comment: Another possibility is that those posts got "bumped" via an edit or other, people saw them on recent activity, and liked them?

Comment: +1 for trying to get serial upvoting reversed.

Comment: 'To larson' is a verb now?  Is this common,eg 'I got totally shogged yesterday:( '

Comment: why would the stack pubish serial voting pseudo code. I once published a question (on Meta) saying take those votes away please. kudos to you too. But based on my blindness, people liked your stuff

Comment: This happened for me too: http://i.imgur.com/4SAHzda.png on Nov 4.

Comment: Looks like the Serial Vote Removal Algorithm is flawed(**?**), as from comments it can be seen that this has been happened with many users.

Comment: @Tushar No, I think Hans Passant comment is valid here "Not unusual for accounts of users from your neck of the woods btw, possibly a skewed sense of patriotism."