# Why aren't my votes being registered?

Tags: bug, voting

I can select to vote on a post or question. Totally not being a points-whore but I have been watching my next badge (Civic Duty) which I'll earn for 300 votes. The thing is, my votes count has stayed at 218/300 for the last couple of days. Now, it's totally possible that I should probably reboot my POS (not "point of sale" if you catch my drift) but I thought it was interesting that the site correctly logs me in, I can comment, and I can view my personal information but the voting portion of the site is being negatively affected somehow.

Details: 
Win7 x86 | Chrome 46.0.2490.80 m

[EDIT] To clarify, the triangles indicate that they have been selected when I select them but if I refresh the page they go back to unselected. [/EDIT]

Comment: Can you see anything useful in your browser's console when you click a vote arrow? It may be that the AJAX requests that sends the vote is denied for some reason. You _do_ may want to reboot your workstation now and then.

Comment: Check in your votes list in your profile page - you may have been voting on posts that were deleted.

Comment: I just went on a Meta-spree and found this: [Why Serial voting is not removed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309499/why-serial-voting-is-not-removed) I am guilty of doing this recently to a user who had low rep and who I felt should have been allowed more access to the site based on how much input they've made. So I went around upvoting their answers. Am I being penalized for Serial Voting?

Comment: It's entirely possible that you _had_ more votes, then your upvote spree was reversed. I see 221 on your badge tracker right now, actually, so I don't think there's actually something wrong here... (The "votes cast" in the right hand side and on the summary tab of your profile are cached, iirc, so those two may take a bit to update.)

Comment: Well, that's weird. Correct @Kendra I just went and voted on a post and it took and my votes changed. But then, I went and voted on another page that I'd had open for the last couple of days and it won't take those. I refreshed that page and it still won't take. I also found my votes tab in my profile. It shows the votes I made but it's not counting them. It says I have 225 votes cast even though my badge counter says 221. It shows the most recent votes but it's not counting them towards the badge. *sigh* I should get back to work. Fricking internet points have me in a lather...

Answer (score 13):

According to your [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309513/why-arent-my-votes-being-registered#comment267085_309513), you've serial voted at least one user. The system detected this and removed your votes. At the time of this post, you have 218 votes:

[image: User's votes]

Anything that was removed via the reversal script does not count. They never existed.

---

A word of advice, vote on content, not the user. If you feel a user "should have been allowed more access", stop. What you did can (and if it continues) will result in a suspension of your account for voting irregularities.

Comment: Yeah I got that made clear by the linked post.